# Redundancy of natural Images in image processing

Tags: matlab

I am trying to figuring out about `correlation` between two images that shifted by pixel each of other and measure the correlation between these images. I have images woods and rooster image like this [rooster image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xkudT.jpg) and [woods image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYHij.png)

and then I doing some code in `matlab` like this

```
Im_Rooster = imread('rooster.jpg'); //read image file
Im_Woods = imread('woods.png');

Im_DRooster = im2double(rgb2gray(Im_Rooster)); //convert to gray image and double data type
Im_DWoods = im2double(Im_Woods);

for i = 0:1:30
    Img_Rooster_shift = circshift(Im_DRooster,i,2); // shift image by 1 pixel 
    Img_Woods_shift = circshift(Im_DRooster,i,2);
    Rooster_correlation_val(1,i+1) = corr2(Im_DRooster,Img_Rooster_shift ); // calculate correlation coefficient between original image and shifted image
    Woods_correlation_val(1,i+1) = corr2(Im_DWoods,Img_Woods_shift );
end

x = 0:1:30;
figure(1),plot(x,Rooster_correlation_val,x,Woods_correlation_val) // plot the result graph
legend('rooster','woods')
```

and then I have plotted graph like this [plot graph result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5O0dS.jpg)

Can somebody explain the meaning of this `graph` result?
What is `correlation` coefficient connection between natural `images`?

Comment: The more you shift the rooster, the less it looks like itself. In the case of the woods, it looks less like itself but each tree kind of stands in for another one because they repeat, so the decrease in similarity is less marked.

Comment: Try it with a pure white image with a single black line, then again with a white image and 5 equally spaced black lines.

Comment: Another reason the woods image tails off less markedly is because it is greyscale, and with the more limited palette, any colour that moves  into a new position as a result of your shifting has less potential to be different from what was there before the shift.

Answer (score 0):

The result imply that in natural images the probability that neighborhood pixel will share same color information is higher than the probability that it will share same light intensity/value. This is naturally explained by the fact that color in nature are result of light-matter interaction, and matter type is not distributed randomly, but usually we will find a collection of same matter in same place, while shadow depends on surrounding space so it can beahve more randomly. 
When you circshift the image you actually compare neighbor pixels, this is auto-correlation but in space. When you ignore the color information than you stay with value/intensity value that can easily have higher frequencies because now we enter to light-shadow realm, that is depend on light angles and matter shape and neighbor shapes and location.